# C# system.management.automation.dll does not start powershell.exe as a new system process

Tags: c#, powershell, azure-powershell

I have worked with Azure powershell from c# application. I have tried system.management.automation.dll as like as below

```
 string scriptPath = @"Microsoft_Image\loadjsontemplate"+i+".ps1";
                var addParametersToScriptFile = new Command(scriptPath);
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("AdUsername", resourceGroup.AdUsername));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("AdPassword", resourceGroup.AdPassword));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("SubscriptionId",resourceGroup.SubscriptionId));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("ResourceGroupName", "testcloud1"+i));
                addParametersToScriptFile.Parameters.Add(new CommandParameter("LocationName", "eastus2"));
                var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                runspace.Open();

                var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();

                var scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

                scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned");
                powerShell.Runspace = runspace;
                var pipeline = powerShell.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
                pipeline.Commands.Add(addParametersToScriptFile);
                pipeline.Invoke();
                pipeline.Dispose();
                runspace.Close();
                runspace.Dispose();
                powerShell.Dispose();
```

the above code does not create new process. if i use multithreading then all runspaces are started in same process. But when i used system.diagnostics.process, it start each request as single process.

```
 string argument = " -ExecutionPolicy ByPass & {& \"D:\\TestingIIS\\Testingparallel\\Testingparallel\\Microsoft_Image\\loadjsontemplate0.ps1\" -ResourceGroupName testcloud2" + i + " -LocationName westus -AdPassword " + resourceGroup.AdPassword + " -AdUserName " + resourceGroup.AdUsername + " -SubscriptionId " + resourceGroup.SubscriptionId + "}";
                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "powershell.exe";
                psi.Arguments = argument;
                psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
                psi.UseShellExecute = false;
                psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = psi;
                process.Start();
                Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
               Console.WriteLine(process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());
```

what is the different between system.management.automation.dll vs system.diagnostics.process?
How can i start separate powershell.exe process in system.management.automation.dll?

Comment: *>How can i start separate powershell.exe process in system.management.automation.dll?* `RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace()` -> `RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null)`

Comment: Hi, when i use RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null) it throws "Cannot perform operation because operation "NewNotImplementedException at offset 43 in file:line:column <filename unknown>:0:0 " is not implemented"